# Shabbat drink mixing

Tags: shabbat

Is one allowed to add lemon powder to water on Shabbat? Especially since it will dissolve on its own? And would it depend on if it’s being saved for after shabbos, or if it’s planned to be drink on shabbat?

Comment: What is your potential concern? Don't people put powdered sugar in coffee or tea?

Comment: There are a couple concerns with putting lemonade powder with water, one would be “dyeing” since it would become yellow, another is that it is transformative in flavor @mbloch but it would still be allowed?

Comment: There is a rule that there is no dying with food, eg you can put as much milk in coffee than you want. I don’t know what transformative in flavor is, eg you can put salt in your cake and it doesn’t make the cake forbidden. In other words I don’t see an issue with lemon powder in water

Comment: I see, is this brought down in shulchan aruch, aruch hashulchan, Mishnah berurah etc.? @mbloch

Comment: Are you asking sources there is no prohibition to color liquids? Many are available, see e.g., https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tzoveya and https://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=3402&PageIndex=66#:~:text=Summary%3A%20One%20may%20add%20essence,is%20indeed%20the%20prevalent%20custom.